# sas hierarchical raw file - no record type identifiers - multiple observations per records

Tags: sas, hierarchical-data

I have a problem importing a hierarchical text file into SAS.
I've been searching for the past week and had no luck.
The problem is that this file does not contain anything that indicates that the detail records are linked with the header.
I have tried the various methods explained with the. `Input @1 Test @` with the `then do`.

Extract of file (every new record starts with `Hong Kong` but each record has a variable number of lines):

```
HONG KONG  
STEEL GROUP  
Invoice Date  
09.12.2015  
Number  
90035565  
Delivery note no.  
80006292  
SAP Order number  
18915  
Customer number  
105226  
Order number  
RCHEB 5114 1-1 24-11   
Shipped from Saldanha bay, South Africa, per vessel  
LAN MAY  
Bill of lading date  
14.11.2015  
Port of discharge  
ANY CHINESE PORT  
Reference no.  
Agreement/Contract/Order  
OMl/24/ll  
Port    Wet Metric Tons Dry Metric Tons  
ANY CHINESE PORT    202,079.000 199,957.171  
Product % USD Value  
Steel Ore   50%;29% 3,500.00  


HONG KONG  
TRADING CORP  
Invoice Date  
21.12.2015  
Number  
90035792  
Provisional Invoice No
90033952
SAP Order number
50005313
Customer number  
102872  
Order number  
KITST 5007 1-1 21-11  
Shipped from Saldanha bay, South Africa, per vessel  
HEBEI SUCCESS  
Bill of lading date  
15.06.2015  
Port of discharge  
BEILUN  
Reference no.  
WUGANG  
Agreement/Contract/Order  
OM6/21/ABG  
Port    Wet Metric Tons Dry Metric Tons  
BEILUN  124,772.000 122,214.174  
Product %   USD Value Sishen 63.5%, 8 mm Fine Ore  
Steel Ore   50%,10% 2,500.00  
Iron Ore    20%,80% 1,500.00
```

Comment: Here
Reference no.  
Agreement/Contract/Order  
OMl/24/ll  
it looks like the value for Reference No is missing.  I would be easier if there was a blank line.  Please clarify that a value can be missing without a place holder.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not an easy way to do this in SAS (that I know of).  I think you are the right track reading the file in, record by record, and writing logic in a data step to parse it.

I would do it like this:

```
data blah;
infile "stuff.txt";
format inStr $2000.;
input inStr $;
if strip(inStr) = "HONG KONG" do;
  ...
end;
else if ... then do;
  ...
end;
...
run;
```